# Synonymize [stackexchange-api] and [api.stackexchange]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Tags [stackexchange-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-api) and [api.stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api.stackexchange) are redundant, can these be merged or made into synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

One of the questions should have been on MSO. I've retagged the other question.